# Google place API implementation and security

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, security, google-places-api

I'm working on a website development with PHP 5.6 and Symfony2 framework. I'm using the [HTTP Google place API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) for a feature.

In my website, the differents call to this API are behind two URL like :

- `/api/location/places/{input}`
- `/api/location/detail/{input}`

From these points, I'm calling Google URL via a CURL library.

My concern is about security. For example, if someone call these URL, then he can consume my own services and so my Google quota (150000 requests / 24 hour period).

I know you can [limiting  IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth#limiting_ip_addresses) in Google console but is it efficient in my case (last IP addresse recorded will be mine in my example) ?

What did you think about this implementation ? Is it safe to control my quota ?